# Trying to use React-google-login just for accessing Google OAuth2 calendar API but giving errors - why?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm really new to OAuth2 so could really use some help. I have a site where users register and login via standard means. However, once they register, I want to connect their Google account so they can view/edit/modify their Google calendars. To this end, I installed react-google-login and have a component on the front-end that logs them into their account. That works fine (here's the code). Please note that the jsx is in styled components, which is why it has odd labels.

```js
return (
    <GoogleContainer>
      <Logo src={GoogleLogo} />
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId = {process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}
        render={(renderProps) => (
          <GoogleBtn
            onClick={renderProps.onClick}
            disabled={renderProps.disabled}
            style={styleObj}
          >
            Connect to Google
          </GoogleBtn>
        )}
        // buttonText='Sign in to Google Calendar'
        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
        isSignedIn={true}
        onFailure={responseError}
        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
        responseType='code'
        accessType='offline'
        scope='openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar '
      />{" "}
    </GoogleContainer>
  );
```

On the backend, I have code that grabs the refresh_token, stores it in a database and then I make a token object that I can send back to the frontend. Here is the code for that -

```js
//This next fx will be used in the CreateTokens fx called by Google Login to identify user by the email captured in scope
const fetchInfo = async (accessToken) => {
  const request = await axios.get(
    `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=${accessToken}`
  );

  let response = await request;
  let email = "";

  if (response) {
    email = response.data.email;
  }

  return email;
};

//Get authorization tokens from google calendar when signing into Google
const createTokens = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { code } = req.body;
    const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);

    accessToken = await tokens.access_token;
    expiryDate = await tokens.expiry_date;
    id_token = await tokens.id_token;

     //Make an object with accessToken and expiry data and send to front end
     const tokenObj = {
      accessToken,
      expiryDate,
      id_token,
    };
    
    //Refresh Token goes to the database
    const refreshToken = await tokens.refresh_token;

    //We find user by using the scope variable from Google Login (frontend) - fx above
    let email = await fetchInfo(accessToken);
    if (refreshToken) {
      //Parameters to update record by putting refreshToken in database
      const filter = { email: email };
      const update = { refreshToken: refreshToken };

      let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
        new: true,
      });
    }
    res.send({ tokenObj });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

That also works fine as I get the refresh_token and store it in the database by user and the tokenObject with the access token gets sent back to the frontend. Here's where I'm confused and can use some help - first of all, I thought I needed to send the token to the frontend to store it but pretty much every time I refresh my page now, the frontend is sending a boatload of information to the console (with tons of information from Google - like the profile, tokens, etc). I don't know what code I wrote that is causing this or if it's a good thing or not. If it's automatically generated, do I even need to have backend code to get the token? Also, I'm getting another message that says " react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Your client application uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."  I thought this was up-to-date and not sure what part is deprecated. Ugh - sorry I'm so new to this and very confused. Any help would be much, much appreciated!!

> Blockquote